# Pandas to_datetime - setting the date when only times (HH:MM) are input

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm new(ish) to python, pandas in particular, and cannot work out how to correctly produce datetimes with `pandas.to_datetime`, when only hours and minutes are provided.

Specifically, I am working with a series consisting of strings such as "08:40 AM", "09:15 AM" ect, stored in a dataframe as `df.hhmm`.

`times  = pandas.to_datetime(df.hhmm)` completes, but associates the times with today's date. e.g. `2015-03-06 09:19:00`

I wish to be able to set the date that these times are associated with e.g. `2015-04-15 09:19:00`

I have a solution that works, but is ugly, e.g.

```
for t in times:
    t.replace(year=2015,month=04,day=15)
```

I'm sure there is a much better way to do this, any tips?

Thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create a string with the full date/time you want and parse that.

so, assuming that `hhmm` is a string, do:

```
pd.to_datetime('20140415 ' + df.hhmm)
```

Comment: Thank you! - that was the nudge I needed. I added `pd.to_datetime('2015-04-15T' + df.hhmm)` and the times came out as wished.